# is an API project as a lambda a good idea?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

So we are deciding on an architecture for a rewrite of an existing API microservice.

The discussion came up to port it to AWS Lambda's but I have a bunch of questions concerning this approach.

Is it at all a good idea to have a full microservice as lambda functions?
These would be used by several different FE projects so the calls to those lambdas would be substantial.

So basically the question I'm posing is:
Is it a good idea to have a microservice with a bunch of API endpoints all created as lambdas when used often or is it generally a better idea to, in this case, have a lightweight nodejs-express server running? And why?

Edit: it would also partially be react serverside rendering

Comment: Primarly opinion based. However, I personally find most of AWS too much of a hassle. I prefer to control entire process. Autoscaling seems like a nice (and the only interesting) feature, but in practice none of the companies I've worked for ever needed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a primary opinion based question (as @freakish said), someone it's going to say yes others are going to say nope.

That being sad here's my 2 cents. I think the real question, that perhaps, you are asking yourself relies in this line:

> These would be used by several different FE projects so the calls to
> those lambdas would be substantial.

That means that you are calling the lambda, let's say, constantly. Thus you might be asking yourself: does it make sense to trade off a little bit of performance? (cold starts).

The first thing I'd to think about is pre-warming a set of functions, so you can avoid cold starts. Of course you should monitor your traffic to see if this is a constant or you have one, or multiple, peeks during the day.

Also ask yourself about concurrency, [here's somewhere you can start from LINK](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/).

AWS Lambda (as other FaaS) comes with this really interesting "things":

- Don't have to manage servers anymore
- Auto scaling built in
- Security built in (less surface attack), but don't give it as guaranteed, you still have to think about it properly. But yeah the attackable surface is much smaller.
- Pay for value

The last point, pay for value, is really interesting. For instance, let's say your audience is mainly based in US, that means that probably you are not going to have everything "up & running" during the night time, thus cutting expenses.

## Some gotchas

Of course there are some paint point that you might not have thought about as you first enter this fancy world of serverless:

- How are you going to handle versioning and ENVs? Try to understand it
- How are you going to debug it?
- What about CI/DI?

As you see this is really broad topic, and we can go and on talking about all the PROs and CONs. You have to do your own searches, and see what really fits better the needs of your architecture.

Talking about the SSR of your react app that's another topic but, personally, I'd not put in a lambda fn, as you are going to have larger packages and that affects cold starts. Perhaps I'd go for AWS EB, or put up an NGINX server with reverse proxy to server multiple apps (if you really need to tear down a FE monolith to micro frontends).

Good luck!